# WCF Data Services message bloat on "related" elements

Tags: wcf-data-services

Looking at the data services messages in fiddler I can't help but think the relationship key is a bit excessive space wise...

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/MyEntity
```

Is there any way to reduce this or remove it completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use projections to only get the links you're interested in (or none).
For example compare this:

http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products(0)

And this:

http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products(0)?$select=ID,Name, Rating

On the other hand if you need the link on the client, then currently the namespace in the rel has to be there. You could use JSON format instead where the links store just the URL, not the rel (well they do, but it's done differently). Unfortunately for now the WCF DS Client doesn't support consuming JSON.

Comment: I do already use projections but I want these links returned.  It just seems like an excessive bit of namespacing...  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Category"

Comment: I updated the answer - there's currently no way to get rid of the rels as they are required by the protocol for the ATOM format. You may be able to use the JSON format which doesn't have them.